# Expected expression before(C Programming Language)

Tags: c, scanf

I am trying to read the data from file pointed by `f` into my struct array: `r_a[]`,
but I am getting the error: `expected expression before r_a"` on the `fscanf()` line.

header file:

```
void setAsset(FILE *f);

  typedef struct rescue_asset{
      char callsign[31];
      char type;
      char location[31];
      double lat;
      double lng;
      double operational_speed;
      int maxDeployDuration;
      int lot_to_service;    
  }r_a[51];
```

c file:

```
#include "rescue_assets.h"
void setAsset(FILE * f)
{
    int i = 0;

    while (getchar() != EOF)
    {
        fscanf(f, "%s %c %s %f %f %f %d %d", &r_a[i].callsign, &r_a[i].type,
               &r_a[i].location, &r_a[i].lat, &r_a[i].lng, &r_a[i].operational_speed,
               &r_a[i].maxDeployDuration, &r_a[i].lot_to_service);

        ++i;
    }
}
```

Comment: Simplify your code. Find the smallest amount that still causes the problem. Then you will see the issue and/or can post it again.

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef struct rescue_asset{
  char callsign[31];
  char type;
  char location[31];
  double lat;
  double lng;
  double operational_speed;
  int maxDeployDuration;
  int lot_to_service;
}r_a_t;

r_a_t r_a[51];
```

as you have to use a variable not a type. Another strange thing is your loop

```
while (getchar() != EOF)
```

you should check for i <51 and fscanf return value

Comment: can I have while(f != EOF)?

Comment: `while( !feof( f ))` it is tecnically usable but it is almost always a bad idea.

Comment: @user2069328 have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong